# Fatal error: Call to undefined function post_exists()

Tags: posts, functions, errors

I am using the function in my own class as I am using other wordpress functions in it.

I am unable to understand why it is not able to find the function while ide "go to declaration" point me to file wp-admin/includes/post.php

is wp-admin files functions do not exist as global.

Comment: You are most probably trying to use it on the front end, which would explain the error. Back end functions are not available on the front end. What are you trying to achieve here. As I said (*in a now deleted comment*), this is a scope issue.

Comment: I am testing my own post exist in the wordpress, I thought builtin function is more appropriate for the job

Comment: Why not just use `get_post()`, if it returns the post, it exists, if not, it does not exist. Otherwise, copy the `post_exists` function to your theme and rename it, then you can use it in the front end

Comment: I want to check the post with title and content already exists ?

Comment: I find the best solution is to copy the post_exists function in my own class, thanks @PieterGoosen, While this function was also suppose to be declared at global level

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The files in `wp-admin` are only loaded when you're in the admin area... when you're looking at pages or posts those functions aren't loaded. In that case you'd need to require the file first, so you'd want to do something like this in your function:

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}
```

The `if ( ! is_admin() )` part is important because WordPress includes the file automatically when `is_admin()` is `true` so you only want to include it if `is_admin()` is `false`. Also make sure to include this snippet *before* you try to call the `post_exists()` function.

If that doesn't work then try this:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'post_exists' ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks :), I don't think its a good idea to include all the functions defined there for checking same title and content post exist

Comment: What's an alternative for checking a post exists by title, without requiring post.php?

Comment: Either will have to write own code for it, else using existing admin function with in function_exists call

Answer (score 1):

You may have used the wrong hook.

I had this problem when using:

```
function my_create_pages() {
    
    if ( !post_exists( "My Title" ) ) {
    
        // Create post
    }
}
add_filter('init', 'my_create_pages');
```

Solution was to use the `admin_init` hook:

```
function my_create_pages() {
    
    if ( !post_exists( "My Title" ) ) {
    
        // Create post
    }
}
add_filter('admin_init', 'my_create_pages');
```