# Why is a wp function used in current PHP namespace's callback not resolved to global scope?

Tags: php, posts, templates, oop, namespace

Imagine the following script:

```
<?php
namespace MySpace;

class MyClass {

  public static function execute() {
    // Do something
    post_exists(1,'','','my_post_type');
  } 

}
?>
```

I'm now calling this function at the top of the page template, before any HTML. The problem I get is that wp resolves the `post_exists` function to the namespace instead of [falling back](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.fallback.php) to the global scope, where wp functions are usually recognized in such cases.

So I actually get a PHP error saying `Call to undefined function MySpace\post_exists()`, why is that so? Is, at that moment, before the document head, the wp core not initiated, or something similar? Never experienced this bug so far...

Comment: Apparently the function can indeed not be used on the frontend in wp (see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218715/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-post-exists)), can anyone confirm this? Would be a huge time-saver if they could mention that little tiny detail in the docs.

Comment: "can anyone confirm this" - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> Apparently the function can indeed not be used on the frontend in wp
> (see
> [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218715/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-post-exists)),
> can anyone confirm this?

I can confirm that the `post_exists()` function *can* be used on the front-end, but you need to manually load the file that defines the function, which is `wp-admin/includes/post.php` — see the "File: `<path>`" part in the "Source" section of the [`post_exists()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/).

And the file has to be manually loaded because WordPress doesn't load it on the non-admin side of the site, or that the function is only loaded automatically in the **wp-admin** area.

> So I actually get a PHP error saying `Call to undefined function MySpace\post_exists()`, why is that so?

I don't know for sure why, but logically thinking, it's because the calling function (`MyClass::execute()`) is in the `MySpace` namespace. So if it wasn't in a namespace, then the message would have not used "MySpace\", i.e. `Call to undefined function post_exists()`.

> The problem I get is that wp resolves the `post_exists` function to
> the namespace instead of [falling
> back](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.namespaces.fallback.php)
> to the global scope

No, I don't think WordPress would not do that "resolves" thing, and what happened is likely this:

1. PHP looked for a function named `post_exists` from the current namespace: `MySpace\post_exists()`.
2. PHP tried to find and call the global function `post_exists()`.
3. Neither found, and so PHP threw the (fatal) error in question.

See the (7th) rule [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) which says, "*For unqualified names, if no import rule applies and the name refers to a function or constant and the code is outside the global namespace, the name is resolved at runtime*".

#### Additional Notes

1. The 1st parameter for `post_exists()` is the post *title*, but it seemed that you've passed an ID (`1`) instead. And if so, then you could just use [`get_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) to check whether the post exists.